# Rails: returning records for which a relationship does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Using active record, how can I return the results for a model if they **do not** exist in a certain relationship elsewhere. For example, say I have a `Recipe` model which belongs to `categories` (via a `category_recipes` join table).

So basically I have a Rake task that looks through each recipe and it's description and try to put in in a category, but the task takes a long time and I'll need to run it on a regular basis, so I only want to run it if the `Recipe` in question has not already been categorized and I'd rather not add a superfluous column like `categorized`, so I figure there is a way to retrieve only the Recipes that don't exist in the join table. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Had to solve this myself today and think this will do the trick:

```
Recipe.includes(:categories).where('categories.id IS NULL').references(:categories)
```

Comment: This is the best answer...  In rails 4 you might need to add references.  Recipe.includes(: category).where("categories.id IS NULL").references(: category)

Comment: Great answer sans all the raw SQL

Answer (score 16):

You can solve this query with a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
Recipe.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN recipe_categories ON recipes.id = recipe_categories.recipe_id').where('recipe_categories.recipe_id IS NULL')
```

Comment: Works great! Feels kind of dirty with all that raw sql in there, but that's probably because I've been used to AREL for so long :D

Answer (score 3):

You could do this with an SQL select, perhaps.

```
@uncategorized_recipes = Recipe.find_by_sql("select * from recipes
  where id not in ( select recipe_id from category_recipes )")
```

The exact syntax might vary depending on your database.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using the pluck method for Recipe and CategoryReceipe.

Steps:

- r = Receipe.pluck(:id)

  > #provides an array of all ids within the model. Ex: [1, 2, 3, 4,
  >   5...]
- cr = CategoryRecipe.pluck(:recipe_id)

  > #provides an array all ids from recipe_id column that are present.
- remainder = r - cr

  > #this takes the two arrays of id and recipe_id and evaluates to a new array. This new array will have only those ids that are not present in CategoryRecipe.

**You can then run your operation on this new array:
Recipe.where(id: remainder).count**

> #gives you the number of records that need to be updated

I prefer this method because you can make it into a seperate function which you can use when evaluating multiple associations without rewriting code. This is also extremely easy to test.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested it but you may try

```
Recipe.joins(:categories).select('recipes.*, categories.count(*) as category_count').where(:category_count => 0).group('recipes.id')
```